# Nested Join Data Inside Linq Result

Tags: c#, linq, join, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a WebAPI that returns Json data for use by jQuery.  It's fairly simple data...  a category and under each category a list of links to websites, each with a title and URL.  I've mocked it up with static data and it works great.  Now, I'm trying to move on to live data.  I have a table with a category id and category title.  Another table hold a link id, category id, link title and link URL.

This represents how I need the link data to be nested with the category only listed once:

```
LegalLinks[] legalLinks = new LegalLinks[]
{
    new LegalLinks {
        Id = 1,
        Title = "Test Category One.1",
        Links = new LinkDetails[]
        {
            new LinkDetails { Title = "Link One", Link = "http://www.google.com/" },
            new LinkDetails { Title = "Link Two", Link = "http://www.google.com/" }
        }
    },
    new LegalLinks {
        Id = 2,
        Title = "Test Category Two.2",
        Links = new LinkDetails[]
        {
            new LinkDetails { Title = "Link Three", Link = "http://www.google.com/" },
            new LinkDetails { Title = "Link Four", Link = "http://www.google.com/" },
            new LinkDetails { Title = "Link Five", Link = "http://www.google.com/" }
        }
    }
};
```

I am able to successfully return just the category data.  Where I fail is the nested link data.  Here are my models:

```
public class LegalLinks_categoriesDTO
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<LegalLinks_linksDTO> Links { get; set; }
}

public class LegalLinks_linksDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string LinkURL { get; set; }
}
```

And my API controller:

```
    private LegalLinksContext db = new LegalLinksContext();

    public IQueryable<LegalLinks_categoriesDTO> GetLegalLinks()
    {
        var legalLinks = from category in db.Categories
                         join link in db.Links on category.Id equals link.CategoryId into categoryLinks
                         from l in categoryLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         orderby category.Title
                         select new LegalLinks_categoriesDTO()
                         {
                             CategoryId = category.Id,
                             Category = category.Title,
                             Links = new LegalLinks_linksDTO { Title = l.Title, LinkURL = l.LinkURL }
                         };

        return legalLinks;
    }
```

I get an error about not being able to convert type LegalLinks_linksDTO to IEnumerable LegalLinks_linksDTO.  I've tried different variations of that line for the past 6 hours, reading everything published about Linq and joins.  How do I get the join data properly nested?

---

### Edit 1

Ok, I found a working solution, using a sub select.  Not sure if this is the most efficient method, but it works and returns the data in the way I need it.

```
    private IQueryable<LegalLinks_categoriesDTO> GetLegalLinks()
    {
        var legalLinks = from category in db.Categories
                         orderby category.Title
                         select new LegalLinks_categoriesDTO()
                         {
                             CategoryId = category.Id,
                             Category = category.Title,
                             Links = from a in db.Links
                                     where a.CategoryId == category.Id
                                     select new LegalLinks_LinkDetails
                                     {
                                         Title = a.Title,
                                         LinkURL = a.LinkURL
                                     }
                         };

        return legalLinks;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I saw you found a solution, but a feedback on other solutions reported in the thread would be welcome. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to assign a `LegalLinks_linksDTO` to an `IEnumerable<LegalLinks_linksDTO>`. This cannot work.

What you can do however is keep the grouping without using `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Example:

```
var legalLinks = from category in db.Categories
                 join link in db.Links on category.Id equals link.CategoryId into categoryLinks
                 orderby category.Title
                 select new LegalLinks_categoriesDTO()
                 {
                     CategoryId = category.Id,
                     Category = category.Title,
                     Links = categoryLinks.Select(l => new LegalLinks_linksDTO { Title = l.Title, LinkURL = l.LinkURL })
                 };

return legalLinks;
```

Comment: Yeah, that one works. Looks kinda like a sub select but selecting items within the join instead of a separate select.  I would assume this would perform slightly faster.

Comment: Just noticed, how would I sort the Links by title?  Adding OrderBy() I cannot seem to find the right value via intellisense.  Would this be correct?     .OrderBy( title => title.Title)

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko if you look at the SQL query, you will notice there's no actual group by, so it should be faster. As for the order by, that looks right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `from l in categoryLinks.DefaultIfEmpty()` statement, and collected categories and relative group of links in an anonymous object, then from that object, I projected the instances of the `_categoriesDto`, and into its initializer list, I made the instance of `_linksDTO` for each item of the links group belonging to a given category.

```
var legalLinks = from category in db.Categories
                 join link in db.Links on category.Id equals link.CategoryId into categoryLinks
                 orderby category.Title
                 select new { category, links = categoryLinks.DefaultIfEmpty() } into dto 
                 select new LegalLinks_categoriesDTO()
                 {
                   CategoryId = dto.category.Id,
                   Category = dto.category.Title,
                   Links = dto.links.First() != null ? dto.links.Select(lnk => new LegalLinks_linksDTO { Title = lnk.Title, LinkURL = lnk.LinkUrl }) : null
                 };
```

This works also for categories without links, the property links will be null (but you can eventually assign it a default value)..

Comment: Using EF, if you're grouping, the group should never be null.

Comment: yes, but if the group is collected with the DefaultIfEmpty()  extension method, as in this case, that is a left outer join, then you may have a null group (or better a collection IEnumerable not null but empty) and so you have to manage this case. In my example I simply return null, but eventually you may provide a default value that represents links collection empty ("no links for this categories")